# Flyway : ERROR: primary key constraints are not supported on partitioned tables

Tags: flyway

My SQL request is correct with an execution in a SQL script.
But when i execute with Flyway, i'm a error.

My request creates a partitionned table with a primary key.
my error:

````
3688 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:7.5.4:migrate (default-cli) on project myProject: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
3688 [ERROR] Migration V12.1.0.1.XXXX__create_table.sql failed
3688 [ERROR] ---------------------------------------------------------
3688 [ERROR] SQL State  : 0A000
3688 [ERROR] Error Code : 0
3688 [ERROR] Message    : ERROR: primary key constraints are not supported on partitioned tables
3688 [ERROR]   Position: 32

Statement  : alter table ma-table add constraint pk_column_id PRIMARY KEY(id,date)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
```
````

Comment: Please also add the SQL statement in question, the start configuration 8what does exist already), and maybe some explaining words.